# What is the meaning of "plant shutdown"

Tags: word-meaning, idiom-request

> When General Motors had a plant shutdown, that was a "volume-related  production-schedule adjustment."
>   [On Writing Well]

I googled the idiom but not much information about. Is this a job? Or sth?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some context. Where did you find it ? Add a little more background details because this is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an idiom. A 'plant shutdown' means the closure of a factory. Plant is a synonym for a factory or an industrial building or a production unit. So a plant shutdown means closing down or shutting down of a plant or a factory.